# Hide certain channels from Dope Sheet?

Tags: animation, keyframes, color, dopesheet

**Greetings,**

I'm working on an animation with 150 objects. I've finished animating and keyframing the objects' transformations, so my next step is to work on their colors.

I would like to solely focus on animating and keyframing the Shader for each object but it is important to know how can I "hide" the Object Transformation channel for all 150 objects and only keep the Shader channel, otherwise it can get a bit confusing.

**Image for reference:**

[image: Hide Channel?]

Also, since I'm working with multiple objects, it would be nice if I could toggle ON and OFF the channel's visibility for all 150 objects at once, and not individually one by one - if possible.

Again, I truly appreciate your time and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dope Sheet has a filter in its header on the right side. There you can choose the types of animation data that you want to have included in the list.

[image]

For materials only, select *Node Trees* and *Materials*, and uncheck the rest.